# WinUI3 create installer with external msi

Tags: windows-installer, winui-3, msix

I'm trying to create an installer for an Winui3 app and add to it an external msi file.

So far I've tried Wix toolset and Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects but both create an msi file containing an exe that doesn't work. The only way that I managed to create an installer with a working launcher was by packaging the desktop application like this https://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/packaging-winui3-desktop/.
The output is an msix file which installs and launches the app. However, I still need to install the external msi file for my app to work.

Are there any solutions for creating and exe installer containing both my project solution msix and the other msi or a way to add prerequisites to packaging the desktop app?